# Facebook Share using shareKit only displays blank screen?

Tags: iphone, facebook, sharekit

i am using shareKit for Facebook/twitter sharing, when facebookSharing button clicked, it gives me the login page, but after first login it only displays a white screen and do nothing.  i have done some editing on SHKConfig.h and entered facebookKey and facebookSecret.

```
#define SHKFacebookUseSessionProxy  NO 
#define SHKFacebookKey          @""
#define SHKFacebookSecret       @""
#define SHKFacebookSessionProxyURL  @"?"
```

while loading, it displays only white screen...

second problem: actually what should i given to the SHKFacebookSessionProxyURL field, is this makes my first problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no one gives me the correct answer, i found two other solutions for adding share functionality, just try this

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381270-addthis-for-ios-quick-start-guide#.T5Yz-1FRr9A

and

http://socialize.github.com/socialize-sdk-ios/getting_started.html#id2

this may helps you

thank you,

Comment: addThis not working with ios 5.0- and socialize not working on ios 4.0-.